# React draw shapes from datas

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have datas that could be represented as such, and I would like to be able to draw a representation of them on my web page, so the users can have a better visualization of what's what.
An item can be part of multiple subcontainers.

[Example of what I'd like to represent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JR7FA.png)

My data would look like this :

```
{
  "name": "Container A"
  "subcontainers": [
    {
      "name": "Subcontainer A"
      "items": [
        {
          "name": "Item 1"
        },
        {
          "name": "Item 2"
        }
       ]
    },
    {
     "name": "Subcontainer B"
     "items": [
       {
         "name": "Item 2"
       },
       {
         "name": "Item 3"
       }
     ]
   }
  ]
}
```

Any idea on how to do so ? Any library I should be looking at to help me drawing this .

Thanks for the help !

So far, I just tried to find a library that would help me draw stuff like this, but not much I could find.

Comment: There isn't much to go on here. Please try providing more information, such as the structure of your data. Also include what you have attempted, or other requirements. Without knowing much more, I would suggest absolutely positioned DOM elements

Comment: I added some json example of what I'd have

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Its not super clear from the question what the desired layout is, but if you are tasked to create elements from some preset structure, I would approach it as shown in the following snippet.

The idea is to loop over each node, and their children as needed, and dynamically create an element and attach it to the parent (or document if the root).

```js
const data = {
  "name": "Container A",
  "subcontainers": [{
      "name": "Subcontainer A",
      "items": [{
          "name": "Item 1"
        },
        {
          "name": "Item 2"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Subcontainer B",
      "items": [{
          "name": "Item 2"
        },
        {
          "name": "Item 3"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
};

function create(parent, label, className, x, y) {
  const element = document.createElement('div');
  element.className = className;
  element.textContent = label;
  element.style.left = `${x}px`;
  element.style.top = `${y}px`;
  parent.appendChild(element);

  return element;
}

Object.keys(data.subcontainers).map((key, i) => {
  const elementData = data.subcontainers[key];
  const parent = create(document.body, elementData.name, 'container', i * 50, i * 80);

  elementData.items.map((sub, i) => {
    create(parent, sub.name, 'subcontainer', i * 50 + 10, 20);
  });
});
```

```css
.container {
  width: 100px;
  font-size: 10px;
  height: 60px;
  border: 1px solid tomato;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 3px;
}

.subcontainer {
  width: 30px;
  font-size: 10px;
  padding: 3px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px dashed tomato;
  position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that kinda looks like what I'm trying to do.
I'd just want that with potential overlapse if an item is in multiple subcontainers, and still keeping it somewhat nice and clean.

Comment: Sure, you can still overlap though - you just need to define the rules for _how_ and _when_ they should overlap. The original question doesn't mention anything like that.